# how to output results of table field from a date range on different tables SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have tables with table headings

**staff**

```
staffID   staffName   staffAge
```

**product**

```
productID   productDescription   productCost
```

**order**

```
orderID   customerID   orderDate   orderLocation
```

**orderServedby**

```
orderID   staffID   servedBy
```

**orderSummary**

```
orderID   customerID   productID   summaryOfOrder
```

I want to get the information from columns `staffID`, `productID` and `orderLocation` depending on who served the order (`servedBy`) between a date (`orderDate`)

I have this so far...

```
SELECT 
    staff.staffID,
    order.orderLocation, orderSummary.productID
FROM 
    staff
INNER JOIN 
    orderServedby ON staff.staffID = orderServedby.staffID
INNER JOIN 
    ordersummary ON product.ProductID = orderSummary.productID
WHERE 
    OrderDate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

I am unsure on how to link them together as they all rely on an `orderID` to get the right columns? Sorry I am very new to SQL. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT 
    staff.staffID,
    order.orderLocation, 
    orderSummary.productID
 from Order
    inner join orderServedBy on orderServedBy.OrderId = Order.OrderId
    inner join orderSummary on orderSummary.OrderId = Order.OrderId
where OrderDate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#
  and ServedBy = '<some value here>'
```